# Merging many time series in r:

Tags: r, merge, xts, zoo

I have 800 time series that I want to merge into one.
They are all xts objects, with dates in coloumn 1 and price in column 2, like this, head(Zoncolan):

```
         Zoncolan    
jun 2007 "  4.585799"
jul 2007 "  4.241864"
aug 2007 "  3.767998"
sep 2007 "  3.504315"
okt 2007 "  3.840607"
nov 2007 "  3.802392"
```

str(Zoncolan) gives the following:

```
An ‘xts’ object on jun 2007/nov 2015 containing:
  Data: chr [1:102, 1] "  4.585799" "  4.241864" "  3.767998" "  3.504315" "  3.840607" "  3.802392" "  5.029093" ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr "Zoncolan"
  Indexed by objects of class: [yearmon] TZ: 
  xts Attributes:  
 NULL
```

I also have saved the names of all the timeseries in the list symbol:
head(symbols)

```
[1] "24Seven Technology Group"                "ABG Sundal Collier Holding"              "ABG Sundal Collier Oil Derivative Long" 
[4] "ABG Sundal Collier Oil Derivative Short" "Ability Drilling"                        "Actinor Shipping"
```

My series are of different length, and I think that is the problem with my merging, but i'm not quite sure. The code I have tried is:

```
> prices = do.call(merge, lapply(symbols, get))
Error in merge.xts(c("12.825", "12.000", " 9.410", " 8.520", " 8.725",  : 
  unsupported data type
```

So the error har something to do with the data type, but I don't quite get it as it is a rather standard xts time series in my opinion.
Anyone that can help me merge these time series together? 
Doesnt quite understand what is the problem.

Comment: Solved. Values was of some reason coded as characters inside the xts files, so converting them resolved the issue.